# SwiftUI - Increment number on long press gesture, then stop once gesture is released

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer

I'm attempting to create a stepper where a number increments rapidly on a longpress gesture and stops when the user releases.

So far, I get the increment to work on the longPress, but when I release the timer still goes, continuing to increment the state.

What can I do to resolve this issue that when the user releases the press, the timer stops.

```
struct CustomFoodItemView: View {
    @State var foodName = ""
    @State var proteinAmount = 1
    @State var carbAmount = 1
    @State var fatAmount = 1
    
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State var isLongPressing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            VStack{
                Text("Food Name")
                TextField("", text: $foodName)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .border(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .frame(width:100, height:10)
            }
            HStack{
                Text(String(proteinAmount) + "g")
                    .frame(width:50, height:50)
                
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("SuccessButtonColor"))
                        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2).onChanged { _ in
                                      print("long press")
                                      self.isLongPressing = true
                            if self.isLongPressing == true{
                                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                                    proteinAmount += 1
                                })
                            } 
                                  }
                                .onEnded { _ in
                            print("stopped") //why won't you stop
                                    self.isLongPressing = false
                                })
                       }
              }
```

[image]

Comment: try to invalidate the timer. Note also that you are setting it to true before checking its value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. You don't stop the timer at all, to stop it, you have to invalidate it (as Leo mentioned). You can do that with `self.timer?.invalidate()`.
2. The `.onEnded`of the `LongPressGesture` will be called when the LongPressGesture has been recognized by pressing the button longer than the minimumDuration time, it does not handle the event when the button will be released. So you don't want to stop the timer on `.onEnded`.

### Combined LongPressGesture and DragGesture

I tried your code and an approach could be to use the `LongPressGesture` to start the timer and a `DragGesture` with a minimum distance of 0 to recognize the button release.

This would look like:

```
struct CustomFoodItemView: View {
    @State var foodName = ""
    @State var proteinAmount = 0
    @State var carbAmount = 0
    @State var fatAmount = 0
    let maxValue = 50
    let minValue = 0
    
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // a drag gesture that recognizes the release of the button to stop the timer, set minimumDistance to 0 to ensure no dragging is required
        let releaseGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onEnded { _ in
                self.timer?.invalidate()
                print("Timer stopped")
            }
        
        // a long press gesture to activate timer and start increasing the proteinAmount
        let longPressGestureIncrease = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2)
            .onEnded { value in
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                    if proteinAmount < maxValue {
                        proteinAmount += 1
                    }
                })
                print("Timer started")
            }


        // a long press gesture to activate timer and start decreasing the proteinAmount
        let longPressGestureDecrease = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2)
            .onEnded { value in
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                    if proteinAmount > minValue {
                        proteinAmount -= 1
                    }
                })
                print("Timer started")
            }
    
        // a combined gesture that forces the user to long press before releasing for increasing the value
        let combinedIncrease = longPressGestureIncrease.sequenced(before: releaseGesture)
    
        // a combined gesture that forces the user to long press before releasing for decreasing the value
        let combinedDecrease = longPressGestureDecrease.sequenced(before: releaseGesture)
        
        VStack{
            
            VStack{
                Text("Food Name")
                TextField("", text: $foodName)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .border(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .frame(width:100, height:10)
            }
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .gesture(combinedDecrease)

                Text(String(proteinAmount) + "g")
                    .frame(width:50, height:50)
                
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .gesture(combinedIncrease)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the gif with the the few items from the code snippet (the number increases after starting the long press and stops when releasing the "+" button):

[image: Increasing number by activated timer]

[image: Indrease and Decrease number by activating timers]

Comment: I have used Sebastian's combined gestures approach and it works fine for incrementing continuously up to the maximum value. Then, I add a button for decrementing and it doesn't work. What it does is decrements momentarily, but returns to the maximum value.

Comment: @MichaelYoung, I updated the code, it now contains both buttons, `+` to increase the number and `-` to decrease the value. It worked for me as you can see in the new attached gif.

Comment: Sebastian, it's not just a matter of +/-1, but setting limits and making sure that you don't go beyond the range established. How you concoct the if statement matters? I found that it was easy to hit the limit and to not go beyond when just repeatedly touching the add or subtract button, but when holding down the button I could reach one end of the range appropriately but then couldn't reverse with either single touches or continuous gestures. The only way to fix the problem was to include self.timer?.invalidate() in the LongPressGesture code, contrary to one of the earlier comments.

Comment: @MichaelYoung I updated the code one more time. I am not sure if if I understand you 100% correctly about what is not working as expected, but now, we have a max limit of 50 and a min value of 0. In a test I was not able to exceed this limits. After increasing the value (to the max value or to a random value) I decreased it again (to the min value or a random value) and it kept it. There was no jump back to another value.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Sebastian Fox for all except that you can do it using single `LongPressGesture` command without the need to `DragGesture` , adding `.updating`to detect when the finger released would help

*here is how it works:*
The `.onEnded` does not detect when you release your finger but it force to action when the button is pressed longer than the `minimumDuration` time, and so it does not handle the event when the button will be released. but you still need to stop the timer on `.onEnded` as a safety in case the view changed for any reason and the state change.

Best way to detect weather the finger is still pressing or has been released is by using `.updating` as I have found in Apple documents here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/longpressgesture

You need to use the `.onChanged` cause no codes should be inside the `.updating` container or it will give you an error so the timer should start inside the `.onChanged`.

The `minimumDuration` need to be set on `.infinity` if you want it keep counting as long as you still pressing otherwise you can make it to any number like 3 seconds so that the maximum time to keep your finger on the screen is 3 seconds then after that it would be forced to stop, after all it is up to you.

The `maximumDistance` defines the maximum distance your finger could be dragged away from the button and it do help the user finger to be more stable as long as he keeps pressing for me I adjust it to `.infinity` which means as long as his finger on the screen no matter where he would be considered still clicking and holding and it would stop when he release, and also it is up to you.

**Single LongPressGesture() handling press and release**

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomFoodItemView: View {

    @State private var foodTimePlus: Timer?
    @State private var foodTimeMinus: Timer?
    @GestureState private var isDetectingLongPress = false
    @State private var completedLongPress = false
    
    @State var foodName = ""
    @State var proteinAmount = 0
    @State var carbAmount = 0
    @State var fatAmount = 0
    @State var direction = false // 0 = add,  1 = subtract
    let maxValue = 50
    let minValue = 0
    

    var longPressPlus: some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity, maximumDistance: .infinity)
           .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentState, gestureState,
               transaction in
               gestureState = currentState
           }
           .onChanged {_ in
               // first click fast start
               if proteinAmount < maxValue {
                   proteinAmount += 1
               }
               
               // then make the timer
               foodTimePlus = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                   check(true)
               })
           }
           .onEnded {_ in
               print("forced to stop")
               foodTimePlus?.invalidate()
           }
    }

    var longPressMinus: some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity, maximumDistance: .infinity)
           .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentState, gestureState,
               transaction in
               gestureState = currentState
           }
           .onChanged {_ in
               
               // first click fast start
               if proteinAmount > minValue {
                   proteinAmount -= 1
               }

               // then make the timer
               foodTimeMinus = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                   check(false)
               })
           }
           .onEnded {_ in
               print("forced to stop")
               foodTimeMinus?.invalidate() // important for safety
           }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Food Name")
                TextField("", text: $foodName)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .border(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .frame(width:100, height:10)
            }
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .gesture(longPressMinus)

                Text(String(proteinAmount) + "g")
                    .frame(width:50, height:50)
                
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .gesture(longPressPlus)
            }
        }

        
    }
    
    func check(_ direction:Bool) {
        // isDetectingLongPress to detect press/release finger
        if isDetectingLongPress == true {
            print("pressed")
            
            if direction == true {
                if proteinAmount < maxValue {
                    proteinAmount += 1
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if proteinAmount > minValue {
                    proteinAmount -= 1
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("release")
            foodTimePlus?.invalidate()
            foodTimeMinus?.invalidate()
        }
    }
    
    
}
```